# Problem starting using clink with lua file

Tags: windows, lua, command-prompt

I would like to use `clink` for my prompt customization, but I really have no ideas where to start to use `clink` within the `lua` files

I have installed both `lua`, `clink`

```sh
lua -v # 5.3.5
clink -h # 0.4.9
```

I have a very `lua` file as shown below

*script.lua*

```lua
print(clink)
print(clink.get_env('CMDER_ROOT'))
```

I tried to execute the script.lua using `lua script.lua`, then I got the result as shown below

*Result*

```
nil
C:\Users\John\scoop\apps\lua\current\lua.exe: script.lua:2: attempt to index a nil value (global 'clink')
stack traceback:
        script.lua:2: in main chunk
        [C]: in ?
```

I also tried using `clink inject && lua script.lua` but the result was nothing at all, no errors

Please guide how to use `clink` from within the `lua` file, thanks.

Comment: Did you load the `clink.lua` file first?

Comment: Where can I get `clink.lua` ? thanks.

Comment: It's in [`cmder/vendor/`](https://github.com/cmderdev/cmder/tree/master/vendor)